# How do i use an Abstract Class in other class (or any class)?

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

I know about **Virtual Class** that they cannot be instantiated, Now I have a question about a case about it, suppose we have a pure abstract class like below:

```
class Color{
public:
    Color();
    virtual string getName()=0;
    ~Color();
};
```

and 2 class inherited form it:

```
class Blue:public Color
{
public:
    Blue();
    ~Blue();
    string getName();
};

class Red:public Color{
public:
    Red();
    ~Red();
    string getName();
};
```

and third class want use `Color` class as its constructor parameter and data member:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(Color&);
    ~Foo();
    void draw(Color&);
private:
    Color* co;
};
```

and its implementation:

```
Foo::Foo():co(new Color()){
}

Foo::Foo(Color &c):co(new Color(c)){
}
```

Now, I know about this part `new Color()` and `new Color(c)` is wrong in this case, but i want only to use a type `Color` to passed to `Foo` and not directly using `Blue` or `Red` as parameter.

what is solution? do i must using overloading or other thing? and for method `draw` do i have any problem?
and i read about **Design Pattern**, does it help me about this case?

tnx for your response.

Comment: Initialize `co` as a null pointer in the default constructor?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg No, i did not use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the constructor that takes a Color&, you can either store a reference or pointer to the passed in color if you can be sure its going to continue to exist, or a smart pointer might be suitable for your use if you want to store a pointer to a previously existing color and ensure its not deleted too soon. Or if you want your class to hold its own copy of the color you can use the clone pattern.
A copy constructor for color would have to return a color (not a class derived from it) which is not possible since color is abstract. Clone would be a virtual function in color returning a color pointer. In derived classes it is implemented to return a new instance of the derived type.

```
class Color
{
    public:
    virtual Color* Clone() const = 0;
};

class Red : public Color
{
    public:
    virtual Red* Clone() const
    {
        return new Red(*this); // updated to use copy constructor
    }
};

Foo::Foo(const Color& c) : co(c.Clone())
{}
```

For the default foo constructor you need to choose whether its OK for foo's color* member to be null, if it is then pass in nullptr as suggested.
If not you can pick a default color to initialise the color*. Note Foo still holds a color* not a Red*. You could specify the default color class with a typedef or using statement, to ensure that you define the default only once:-

```
using DefaultColour = Red;
Foo::Foo() : co(new DefaultColour()) {}
```

Or just don't give Foo a default construct - insist that a Color is provided

Comment: tnx very for your excellent exapalation, i am new in c++ and  you said about smart pointer, can you tell me how do i use it if you like and you said about default color class with typedef or using statement how do i do that? is DefaultColour  class?

Comment: regarding the default colour - that's the using statement in the example above. (typdef would be an older style way to do the same thing). Its an alias for your class, in this case I'm saying the default is red, I can then refer to DefaultColour wherever I need it, but if I decide to change the default to Blue, there's only one line that needs changing (the line with using). It also helps make the code self-documenting in that when you use DefaultColor it shows you use it because its the default, not anything special about it being red or blue.

Comment: regarding the smart pointers - best to look them up, I couldn't cover it all, and how you'd need to use it would depend on what happens to the color object you were passing into the Foo constructor. The reason I mention it though is that if you store a pointer to an object that was passed into the constructor, you don't want that object to be deleted elsewhere and have you foo class still pointing at memory where the object that no longer exists used to be.

Comment: note also that given I made Clone a const function, the parameter passed into Foo would have to be const too. Foo::Foo( const Color& c)

Comment: can i pass parameter ot clone() method if i have any data member(or different data) for Red or Blue?

Comment: you could, if you add it in base color and all derived versions of clone, but I'm not sure what you'd use it for. Clone means "I know this object derives from color - but I don't know what derived color it actually is, but whatever it is give me a copy of that"

Comment: ok tnx i understand main of your experienced explanation, +1 for your answer.

Comment: I misunderstood your last question - you shouldn't need to pass a parameter, because Clone should have been implemented to call the copy constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120147/discussion-between-mehdi-and-rox).

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your member pointer to `nullptr`:

```
Foo::Foo() : co(nullptr) {}
Foo::Foo(Color &c) : co(nullptr) {}
```

Comment: Looks like a possible solution for the default constructor, but rather odd to have a version of the constructor that takes a color and ignores it.